# Auto correct a field?

Tags: visualforce, custom

I have one field Registration number.it is of type xxxxxxx-xx-xxxxxx.Now i want that if user enter all correct digits but no dashes then It should be autocorrect and by passes the validation rule.How can i implement it.My field is of Text type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Standard UI Route:**

You didn't mention if you are using Visualforce or not. If you wanted a standard UI solution. Then a combination of a formula field and your text field may provide the formatting you need. The standard text field would need some validation, to check length and prevent dash '-' characters being entered.

[image]

The formula for the second field would look like this...

```
MID( Registration_Number__c , 1, 7) + '-' + MID( Registration_Number__c , 8, 2) + '-' + MID( Registration_Number__c , 10, 6)
```

**Other Options**

- Visualforce, this might be more than you want to get into for a single field.
- Apex Trigger to accept various formats and reformat it before updating the record.

**Visualforce Route:**

If you are using Visualforce, then you have the ability in your Apex controller to process (via your action method) a Registration Number member variable bound to a apex:inputText. Either as containing valid dash's or if there is none add them. Then update the real Registration Number field on your object prior to updating or inserting. For the purposes of those editing your records outside of your Visualforce page I would still retain the validation rule however.

**VisualForce and JQuery Route:** Beyond this, if your comfortable with jQuery, then there are a number of [plugins](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) that can help with masked edit fields.

[image]

[image]

Comment: using Visualforce

Comment: Ok updated my answer with some thoughts on this, not sure how much VF and Apex you know, so hopefully this is enough for you to progress further. Let me know.

Comment: Your very welome! Enjoy!